# Invalid command name "::tk::dialog::file::"

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, archlinux

I'm trying to open a simple file open dialog in Tcl/Tk but whenever I run `tk_getOpenFile` I get the following error:

```
invalid command name "::tk::dialog::file::"
    while executing
"::tk::dialog::file:: open {*}$args"
    (procedure "tk_getOpenFile" line 5)
    invoked from within
"tk_getOpenFile"
    (procedure "open" line 2)
    invoked from within
...
```

I'm running the latest version of Tcl/Tk, 8.6.9, from the Arch Linux repositories.  What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a broken installation somehow. The procedure `tk_getOpenFile` in `…/tk.tcl` (where `…` is where Tk's library files are installed) delegates to the procedure `::tk::dialog::file::` in `…/tkfbox.tcl` (yes, an unusual procedure name), but that doesn't seem to be working in your case. Either the file is missing, or the `tclIndex` file in the same directory is broken. (That's using an old mechanism for auto-loading of code that doesn't really make sense for new code to use in… well, in this millennium. It's kept for backward compatibility.)